# (Typescript) How do you set pointRadius, pointHoverRadius, ect in ChartJs 3.7.0 & react-chart-js-2 4.0.1

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

**Edit:** This appears to only be an issue if you are using typescript. Thank you @LeeLenalee

I recently upgraded package versions

**chart.js** -- 3.2.1 -> 3.7.0

**react-chartjs-2** -- 3.0.3 -> 4.0.1

Which broke my line chart:

```js
 <Line
  data: {...}
  options: {
    pointRadius: 0,
    pointHoverRadius: 5,
    pointHitRadius: 20,
    pointBackgroundColor: ...,
  }
 />
```

The docs are fairly difficult to find this info.  Even after I figured out how to change it and I look back at the docs I still can't make much sense of them.

**Edit: Typescript error**
[image]

Comment: This works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/o8catw7L/, Also tried it in my local react-chartjs-2 project and also worked fine

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, this appears to be a typescript only issue then.

Comment: Updated question to more obviously show this is a typescript issue.  Would appreciate removing your negative vote.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is multiple ways to set the point options.  For me I was able to set the global point options in **options.elements.point**.

```js
 <Line
  data: {...}
  options: {
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0,
        hoverRadius: 5,
        hitRadius: 20,
        backgroundColor: ...,
      }
    }
  }
 />
```

These options can also be set (or override global settings) in your dataset object as well for each line.

```js
 <Line
  data: {
   datasets: [{
     pointRadius: 0,
     pointHoverRadius: 5,
     pointHitRadius: 20,
     pointBackgroundColor: ...,
   }] 
  }
 />
```